# Is the closure of a topological torsion LCA group still topological torsion?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Suppose $G$ is a locally compact abelian (LCA) group and

$f: H \rightarrow G$

a continuous group homomorphism, where $H$ is a topological torsion group. Does it follow that the topological closure of the image in $G$ is again topological torsion?

(Edit: A group is $\textit{topologically torsion}$ if $\operatorname{lim}_n n! x = 0$ for all $x$ in the group, or equivalently (by a theorem of Robertson) if  every character on the group takes values in Q/Z (as opposed to R/Z), or equivalently if both $G$ and its Pontryagin dual are simultaneously totally disconnected)

Comment: Please define topological torsion.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For instance, let $H$ be the discrete group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, $G=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and let $f$ be the natural inclusion map.  Then the image of $f$ is dense in $G$, but $G$ is not topologically torsion.